# Symfony2: How to hide link in Twig based on permissions

Tags: security, symfony, twig

My application shows a list of projects, project detail pages and forms to edit these projects. These are the routes:

- / - list of projects
- /project/42 - view project (project detail page)
- /project/42/edit - edit project

Only its owner may edit a project.

I have implemented a Voter to prevent access to /project/42/edit for non-owners.

Now, I also want to hide the link "edit project" from the project detail page. What would be the way to do this? Ideally, in Twig, I would like to do something like

```
{% if may_access(path('project_edit', { 'id': project.id })) %}
  <a href="{{ path('project_edit', { 'id': project.id }) }}">edit project</a>
{% endif %}
```

I can implement this function as a Twig extension, but maybe a similar functionality already exists.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function is_granted() actually [has a second parameter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#functions) that allows me to do just what I need:

```
{% if is_granted("MAY_EDIT", project) %}
  <a href="{{ path('project_edit', { 'id': project.id }) }}">edit project</a>
{% endif %}
```

I use this in combination with a check in the controller action:

```
public function editAction(Project $project)
{
    if (!$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('MAY_EDIT', $project)) {
        $this->flash('You are not allowed to edit this project');
        return $this->show($project);
    }
    // ...
}
```

This is actually very similar to the approach that [nifr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832745/nifr) used in his answer to [Sonata User - Security on custom field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020762/sonata-user-security-on-custom-field/17035423#17035423). I was hoping to find a way to have the voter be called automatically and avoid the call to isGranted().

If you want to have a look at the complete code, it is in the tutorial project I have [published in github](https://github.com/cocomore/fuxcon2013_symfony).

Comment: Please be advised, anyone can url hack.  Make sure your controller has the appropriate redirects as well.

Comment: Nice work. One thing to note, if `$this->show($project);` is just returning the same view as the project page (/project/42). It would probably be best to use a 302 redirect to that route.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my $this->show($project) is actually just a small helper that does return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('project_show', array('id' => $project->getId())));

Comment: Excellent :) Btw, if you want to reply to someone in a comment on Stackoverflow you can write in their username like `@Paulpro` and then they receive a notification that you've replied to them :)